# how to restrict user to touch chrome title bar and 3 vertical dots on mobile

Tags: javascript

I have a website where i want to restrict user to touch chrome title bar, tab menu and 3 vertical dots on mobile. I am just wondering using js is it possible!. If it is possible please give some code refrence..Thanx::Sohon[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrm1k.jpg)

Comment: No, you can't restrict the chrome UI using javascript.

Comment: The only way to do that is to ship a custom browser that doesn't have that feature. You can not prohibit access to the interface controls otherwise.

Comment: can I prevent the touch of the upper bar!

Comment: If that were possible, a million annoying people would abuse it for the most annoying things possible.

Comment: i have google and found a code to restrict user to swipe from the top to refresh, though I was thinking!

Comment: Have one more question, this question is asked before but I hav'nt found the sollution I want, "Submit a form on browser close"..I have just found an alert using window.onbeforeunload ..So is it possible in anyway?

Comment: @SohonShome please take what you have read and try to create some code for yourself. Then, if you have problems, post your code and then the community can help guide you.

Comment: see -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) and set it's `display` to `standalone` in it's [manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/), which will hide the browser's UI.

This will only hide the UI once the user installs the PWA on their phone though (i.e. they have to 'approve' you to hide the browser UI from them)